# Kafka Mongodb sink connector - update document

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

we have been working on kafka ecosystem. let me go through the flow

**Source(SQLServer) -> Debezium(CDC) -> Kafka Broker -> Kafka Stream(Processing, joins etc) -> Mongo connector -> Mongo DB**

Now we are in last step, we are inserting processed data into mongo dB but now we have requirement to upsert data instead just insert.

Can we get upsert(insert/update) functionality from mongo sink connector. as for now I understand it cant be done.

Comment: Have you tried looking over github issues for that connector?

Comment: Yes I have tried and still trying.

Comment: Can you clarify which Mongo sink connector you're using? (I'm not aware any support update or delete), but just curious

Comment: I am using **com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector** connector class

Comment: If you want updates and/or deletes, you would have to add logic around this line to handle that accordingly https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-kafka/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mongodb/kafka/connect/sink/MongoSinkTask.java#L177

Comment: Thanks let me go through

Comment: Can we go  with this **com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.mongodb.sink.MongoSinkConnector** ?? because it has kcql with insert and update support

Comment: Is there something preventing you from using it?

Comment: my client actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the provided link , it has all the information about kafka mongo connector. i have successfully implemented upsert functionilty.you just need to read this document carefully.

[Kafka Connector - Mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/master/kafka-sink-postprocessors/)

Comment: I just posted an answer too .-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245208/can-we-update-upsert-a-record-in-mongodb-data-source-is-kafka/60705264#60705264

Comment: Accepted answer on @Shubh's thread worked for me...

Answer (score 2):

Effectively this is an upsert, we want to insert if the ${uniqueFieldToUpdateOn} is not in mongo, or update if it exists as follows.

There are two main ways of modelling data changes in a collection depending on your usecase update/replace as outlined below:

**UPDATE**

The following config states:

1. Update ${uniqueFieldToUpdateOn} with a field that is unique to that record that you want to model your update on.
2. AllowList (whitelist) this field For use with the `PartialValueStrategy` allows custom value fields to be projected for the id strategy.
3. UpdateOneBusinessKeyTimestampStrategy means that only the one document referenced by the unique field declared above will be updated (Latest timestamp wins).

```
"document.id.strategy":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.PartialValueStrategy", 
"document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.list":"${uniqueFieldToUpdateOn}",
"document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.type":"AllowList",
"writemodel.strategy":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.UpdateOneBusinessKeyTimestampStrategy"
```

**REPLACE**

NB this models a REPLACE not an update but may be useful none the less

The following config states:

1. Replace ${uniqueFieldToUpdateOn} with a field that is unique to that record that you want to model your replace on.
2. AllowList (whitelist) this field For use with the `PartialValueStrategy` allows custom value fields to be projected for the id strategy.
3. ReplaceOneBusinessKeyStrategy means that only the one document referenced by the unique field declared above will be replaced.

```
"document.id.strategy":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.PartialValueStrategy", 
"document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.list":"${uniqueFieldToUpdateOn}",
"document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.type":"AllowList",
"writemodel.strategy":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.ReplaceOneBusinessKeyStrategy"
```

Comment: i've used the same configurations suggested but I'm not able to succesfully make the connector run its failing im getting the error  `org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Could not convert key 456 into a BsonDocument.\n\tat com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.converter.LazyBsonDocument.getUnwrapped(LazyBsonDocument.java:157)\n\tat com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.converter.LazyBsonDocument.clone(LazyBsonDocument.java:146)\n\tat com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.converter.SinkDocument.clone(SinkDocument.java:45)\n\tat `  is there an example connector for this that i can use as reference

Comment: can u show me your connector configuration and maybe I can help u?

Comment: since i can't post the full connector in one go ill put it in parts first part is 
** "name":"tag-update2","config":{"connector.class":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector","tasks.max":"1","connection.uri":"mongodb://xx.xx.xx:27017","database":"staff","collection":"user","topics":"user_update_new1","key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter","value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter" **

Comment: the other half is **"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8081",

"document.id.strategy":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.PartialValueStrategy",
"document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.type":"user_id",
"document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.type":"AllowList",
"writemodel.strategy":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.ReplaceOneBusinessKeyStrategy"
}
}** apologies for not being able to send it as a whole

Comment: first things first you have document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.type twice, you should have document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.list with "user_id", also can u show me the payload of the message you are sending including the key? looks like issue  converting the key

Comment: also you probably dont need schema registry config if you are not using avro, unless you intennd to be then u will need to change your converter to: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter

Comment: I'm actually using the json schema seralizer for pythoh kafka to publish the data the key is serialiszed with StringSerializer function and yeah i updated the duplicate you pointed out but no luck

Comment: i used this format to publish the data [https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/json_producer.py]

Comment: can u show me the key and value for the payload that is generated? Log them out somewhere and once u have those we can see why the payload is not being converted properly, I'd imagine its generating invalid json

Comment: i used kafkacat to pull the data from the topic it looks like so `{"topic":"tag-update","partition":0,"offset":6,"tstype":"create","ts":1605589866512,"broker":-1,"key":"456","payload":"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0006{\"client_id\": 1, \"default\": true}"}`

Comment: 2 issues: 
1. You are using a json converter for your key, yet u are passing a string as ur key which is not json.
2. looks like the payload is a combination of byte array and escaped json look at how u are generating your payload. Fix the message and it will all work